# Tailwind CSS and different border styles for div

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I do want to convert this to Tailwind

```html
<div
  style={{
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    borderLeft: "9px solid transparent",
    borderRight: "9px solid transparent",
    borderBottom: `8px solid  ${
      isCardExpired ? "rgb(250,77,86)" : "rgb(232,125,26)"
    }`,
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto"
  }}
></div>
```

This will generate a triangle shape in CSS.

So far I tried to convert it like this

```html
<div className="w-0 h-0 border-x-8 border-solid border-transparent mx-auto"></div>
```

How do I add this part

```
borderBottom: `8px solid  ${
  isCardExpired ? "rgb(250,77,86)" : "rgb(232,125,26)"
}`
```

This is my [Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-starter-forked-q4mt6v?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your code like in below example:

```
<div className={`w-0 h-0 border-8 border-solid border-transparent mx-auto border-${isCardExpired ? '[rgb(250,77,86)]' : '[rgb(232,125,26)]' }`} ></div>
```

However what you are trying to achieve is difficult through tailwind CSS, as Tailwind CSS is primarily designed for utility-first and atomic CSS classes. Complex border styling like the one you described might not be achievable with Tailwind classes alone. You will have to use like below

```
function App() {
  const isCardExpired = true;
  const borderColor = isCardExpired ? 'border-red-600' : 'border-orange-500';

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className={`w-0 h-0 ${borderColor} border-b-8`} style={{ borderLeft: '9px solid transparent', borderRight: '9px solid transparent' }}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It could potentially work, however, you are missing syntax with regards to the colors, it should be prepended with `border-` and secondly, it does not allow you code completion in you IDE with template strings, and lastly, could potentially be overridden with other styles. clsx and tailwind-merge ensures correct CSS class inheritance.

Comment: its already prepended with border- , check again. However what he is trying to achieve is difficult through tailwind CSS, as Tailwind CSS is primarily designed for utility-first and atomic CSS classes. Complex border styling like the one you described might not be achievable with Tailwind classes alone. He will have to use like below

Comment: function App() {
  const isCardExpired = true;
  const borderColor = isCardExpired ? 'border-red-600' : 'border-orange-500';

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className={`w-0 h-0 ${borderColor} border-b-8`} style={{ borderLeft: '9px solid transparent', borderRight: '9px solid transparent' }}></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: Apologies for not being clear, you cannot create composite classes dynamically: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names "If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a utility like [tailwind-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) or [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) like this:

```
<div 
  className={
    clsx("w-0 h-0 border-x-8 border-solid border-transparent mx-auto", 
    isCardExpired 
      ? "border-[rgb(250,77,86)]" 
      : "border-[rgb(232,125,26)]")} 
/>
```

You can also add the `rgb` colors to your theme for easier use:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: { ... },
    colors:{
      custom1: 'rgb(12,159,100)',
      custom2: 'rgb(232,125,26)'
      ...
    }
  },
  plugins: [...],
}
```

And then use it as:

```
<div 
  className={
    clsx("w-0 h-0 border-x-8 border-solid border-transparent mx-auto", 
    isCardExpired 
      ? "border-custom1" 
      : "border-custom2")} 
/>
```

Edit: explanation of [Tailwind border dimensions are here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width). You already have `border-x-8 border-solid` which is not part of the conditional, so it will work as you posted. If you need the width and height to be 8px, then you can change the `border-x-8` to `border-8`. If as you stated only bottom then `border-b-8` instead of `border-x-8`.

Comment: It should be border bottom 8px part as well

Comment: Updated the explanation for you.

Comment: @margheritapizza - is that clearer?